# Stata - How to Generate Random Integers

Tags: random, integer, stata

I am learning Stata and want to know how to generate random integers (without replacement).  If I had 10 total rows, I would want each row to have a unique integer from 1 to 10 assigned to it.  In R, one could simply do:

```
sample(1:10, 10)
```

But it seems more difficult to do in Stata.  From [this Stata page](http://blog.stata.com/tag/random-numbers/), I saw:

```
generate ui = floor((b-a+1)*runiform() + a)
```

If I substitute a=1 and b=10, I get something close to what I want, but it samples with replacement.

After getting that part figured out, how would I handle the following wrinkle: my data come in pairs.  For example, in the 10 observations, there are 5 groups of 2.  Each group of 2 has a unique identifier.  How would I arrange the groups (and not the observations) in random order?  The data would look something like this:

```
obs   group  mem     value
1     A      x       9345
2     A      y       129
3     B      x       251
4     B      y       373
5     C      x       788
6     C      y       631
7     D      x       239
8     D      y       481
9     E      x       224
10    E      y       585
```

`obs` is the observation number.  `group` is the group the observation (row) belongs to.  `mem` is the member identifier in the group.  Each group has one `x` and one `y` in it.

Comment: You can also read _part 2_ of that Stata blog series: http://blog.stata.com/2012/08/03/using-statas-random-number-generators-part-2-drawing-without-replacement/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First question:

You could just shuffle observation identifiers.

```
set obs 10
gen y = _n 
gen rnd = runiform()
sort rnd
```

Or in Mata

```
jumble(1::10)
```

Second question: Several ways. Here's one.

```
gen rnd = runiform() 
bysort group (rnd): replace rnd = rnd[1] 
sort rnd
```

General comment: For reproducibility, set the random number seed beforehand.

```
set seed 2803
```

or whatever.

Comment: In the solution to the second question, why do we need to include (rnd) in the bysort statement.  Could we leave it out?

Comment: Yes; that would be another way to do it.